# Model considering a single tensor as batch input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've coded a custom TensorFlow model. However, when I pass in single tensor to it, it considers each element of that tensor as single input and therefore, gives a batch output.

For eg. my input tensor is of the shape [3,1] with values:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.7001484 ]
 [0.2581525 ]
 [0.04169908]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Corresponding to this I should get a single vector of shape (3,). But what I'm getting is 3x3 tensor:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.31234854 0.3224371  0.36521438]
 [0.32561225 0.3294511  0.3449366 ]
 [0.33208787 0.33271718 0.33519495]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

**My Model**

```
class MAE_Model(tf.keras.Model):

def __init__(self):
    super(MAE_Model, self).__init__()
    self.h_fin = EnsembleBlock() 
    self.ipt = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(3,1), batch_size=None)
    self.fc_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')
    self.fc_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')
    self.classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')

def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.h_fin(inputs) # this returns a vector of shape [3] E.g. x = [1., 2., 3.]
    x = tf.reshape(x, (3,1)) 
    print(x)
    x = self.ipt(x)
    x = self.fc_1(x)
    x = self.fc_2(x)
    return self.classifier(x)
```

Here, print(x) prints a (3,1) tensor, similar to the example above. Is there any way to solve this? **I want the model to consider the x as a single input (whole of it) and not as some batch input**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your model makes sense. The reason it gives a 3x3 tensor is because the last layer in your model outputs probabilities corresponding to 3 classes. So, given a batch of 3 inputs, your output will have probabilities for 3 classes for each element in your batch. If you want to find the predicted class, you want the classes with the highest probability. Tensorflow allows you to easily find the classes by doing

```
tf.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
```

The corresponding output shape from this operation will be of shape (None,) where None is the batch size.

Comment: Hi I don't mean to pass a batch. What I want is that let x = [1., 2., 3.], i.e. a vector of shape [3]. I want my model to consider it as a single input and output a single vector corresponding to this. So should I reshape my input to some other shape?

Comment: In tensorflow, a model must be given a batch to make predictions. In this case, since x is one data point that you want to make predictions, you can call tf.expand_dims(x, axis=0) to give your data point a batch dimension of size 1. This allows you to feed it into your model.